# New rows in tabular form won't decrement

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code runs on a page that gives you the ability to add and delete rows from a table of input fields. It works for existing fields, but when I add new rows and try to delete them in an order that requires replacing the ID and name attributes it doesnt work - it will not replace the ID and name attributes. Any ideas what's going on?

The following function is supposed to decrement the remaining rows after the current row that is going to be deleted has been passed in the loop, and replace the number in the ID and name attributes. Then delete the row.

```
 $("#tblData").delegate("button", "click", function()
       {

           var id1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').attr('id');


           id1 = parseInt(id1.match(/\d+/));


         var count = 0;
         var ID;
         var name;
         var str;
         var str2;
         var n1, n2;
            $('#tblData > tbody > tr').each(function() {
              $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                    //do your stuff, you can use $(this) to get current cell

                    if ($(this).children().children().next().prop("tagName") == "INPUT")
                    {                            
                        if (count > id1){
                            // get id and name attributes
                            ID = $(this).children().children().next().attr("id");
                            name = $(this).children().children().next().attr("name");
                            // match number and replace number in ID
                            str=ID;
                            n1=parseInt(str.match(/\d+/));
                            n1 = n1-1;           
                            ID = ID.replace(/\d+/,n1);


                            // match number and replace number in name
                            str2=name;
                            n2=parseInt(str2.match(/\d+/));
                            n2 = n2-1;    
                            name = name.replace(/\d+/,n2);


                            $(this).children().children().next().attr("id",ID);
                            $(this).children().children().next().attr("name",name);
                        }                        
                    } else if ($(this).children().children().next().prop("tagName") == "SELECT") {

                        if (count > id1){
                            ID = $(this).children().children().next().attr("id");
                            name = $(this).children().children().next().attr("name");
                            // match number and replace number in ID
                            str=ID;
                            n1=parseInt(str.match(/\d+/));
                            n1 = n1-1;            
                            ID = ID.replace(/\d+/,n1);           

                            // match number and replace number in name
                            str2=name;
                            n2=parseInt(str2.match(/\d+/));
                            n2 = n2-1;      
                            name = name.replace(/\d+/,n2);

                            $(this).children().children().next().attr("id",ID);
                            $(this).children().children().next().attr("name",name);
                        }          
                    }
                });                                     
                count = count + 1;

           });  

        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       }
    );
```

Append row function

```
function Add(){

var id = $( "#tblData tbody tr:last-child td input" ).attr('id');

id = parseInt(id.substring(12, 13)) + 1;

//alert(id);
    $("#tblData tbody").append(
            "<tr>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_Room_No'>Room  No</label><select single='single' size='1' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][roomId]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_roomId'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_startDate' class='required'>Start Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][startDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_startDate' type='text' /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_endDate' class='required'>End Date <span class='required'>*</span></label><input name='BookingRoom["+id+"][endDate]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_endDate' type='text'  /></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_adults' class='required'>Adults <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][adults]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_adults'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><label for='BookingRoom_children' class='required'>Children <span class='required'>*</span></label><select single='single' size='5' name='BookingRoom["+id+"][children]' id='BookingRoom_"+id+"_children'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></td>"+
            "<td><button type='button'>Delete</button></td>"+
            "</tr>");

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `delegate`, use `on` instead :

```
$("#tblData").on("click", "button", function()
```

By the way, you'll prefer use double quote character instead of single quote character to wrap HTML attributes.

And you're encapsulating too many time `this` with jquery in your function... a good practice is to never call twice the same element with jquery, store it in a variable instead :

```
var $that = $(this); // put a $ before your var to remember that it is a jquery element
```